# Multiple delaration of objects, they set "empty"

Tags: excel, vba, object, worksheet

I've set multiple `Worksheet` objects, only the last object is set `Nothing`, the first X are `empty`

Multiple line declaration is working

```vb
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

If ws1 is nothing then
If ws1 = "" then
If ws1 = "Empty" then
If ws1 = vbEmpty then
If IsEmpty(ws1) then
If IsNull(ws1) then

    'tried all of these but get
    'runtime error


If ws2 is nothing then

    'works fine
```

```vb
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

If ws1 is nothing then

    'works fine

If ws2 is nothing then

    'works fine
```

Follow-Up because of answer from Pᴇʜ:

```
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

If ws1 Is Nothing Or IsEmpty(ws1) then

    'runtime error

If IsEmpty(ws1) then

    'works fine

If ws2 Is Nothing then

    'works fine
```

> runtime error 424

I just want to make the code cleaner with multiple line declarations, maybe it's not possible

**Conclusion:**
We have to declare each variable separately!
Further details in the first answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"I've set multiple 'worksheet' objects"*

No, you didn't.

If you declare

```
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
```

then `ws2` is of type `Worksheet` but `ws1` is of type `Variant` because you didn't specify a type for the first variable. Therefore `ws1` is not an object unless you set it to one, and `If ws1 Is Nothing Then` fails because it can only be used with objects.

It is exactly the same as

```
Dim ws1 As Variant, ws2 As Worksheet
```

If you declare multiple variables in one line (in VBA) you still need to specify a type for **every** variable (or it will be `Variant` by default):

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
```

***Note:***
*This is only valid in VBA. If you also use VB.NET be carefull because there `Dim a, b As Long` will define **both** variables as `Long`! In VBA it doesn't!*

---

Follow up answer:

The following `If` statement …

```
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
If ws1 Is Nothing Or IsEmpty(ws1) then
```

errors, because in `If` statements with `Or`/`And` operators always all of the tests are performed no matter what the result of the others is. So in this case it tests both `ws1 Is Nothing` and `IsEmpty(ws1)`.

The first one errors because `ws1` is `Variant` and not an object but `Is Nothing` only works with objects. Therfore the whole statement errors.

Comment: Okay, but why fails the following if-statement:
```
If ws_1 Is Nothing Or IsEmty(ws_1) Then
    'do something
    'getting runtime error
End If
```

Comment: @Patrick because `Is Nothing` expects an object but if `ws1` is `Variant` it is not an object and therefore it fails.

Comment: @Patrick In a `If` statement with `Or` or `And` operators aways **all** tests are performed. If one errors the whole `If` statement errors. Since `Is Nothing` errors the whole statement doesn't work.